# sharing information among two sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, process

I'm trying to implement a UDP-based server that maintains two sockets, one for controlling(`ctrl_sock`) and the other for data transmission(`data_sock`). The thing is, `ctrl_sock` is always uplink and `data_sock` is downlink. That is, clients will request data transmission/stop via the `ctrl_sock` and data will be sent to them via `data_sock`.

Now the problem is, since the model is connection-less, the server will have to maintain a list of registered clients' information( I call it `peers_context`) such that it can "blindly" push data to them until they ask to stop. During this blind transmission, clients may send controlling messages to the server via the `ctrl_sock` asynchronously. These information, besides initial Request and Stop, can also be, for example, preferences of file parts. Therefore, the `peers_context` has to be updated asynchronously. However, the transmission over the `data_sock` relies on this `peers_context` structure, hence raises a synchronization problem between `ctrl_sock` and `data_sock`. My question is, what can I do to safely maintain these two socks and the `peers_context` structure such that the asynchronous update of `peers_context` won't cause a havoc. By the way, the update of `peers_context` wouldn't be very frequent, that is why I need to avoid the request-reply model.

My initial consideration of the implementation is, to maintain ctrl_sock in the main thread(listener thread), and transmission over `data_sock` is maintained in the other thread(worker thread). However, I found it is difficult to synchronize in this case. For example, if I use mutexes in `peers_context`, whenever the worker thread locks `peers_context`, the listener thread wouldn't have access to it anymore when it needs to modify `peers_context`, because the worker thread works endlessly. On the other hand, if the listener thread holds the `peers_context` and writes to it, the worker thread would fail to read `peers_context` and terminates. Can anybody give me some suggestions?

By the way, the implementation is done in Linux environment in C. Only the listener thread would need to modify `peers_context` occasionally, the worker thread only needs to read. Thanks sincerely!

Comment: Why not use TCP? You can set up a stream based connection with each client and perform the necessary communication without any worry of synchronizing it. Way easier and way more reliable than UDP.

Comment: Sounds like you just need slightly more sophisticated locking.  Clearly you can't just have worker hold lock endlessly.  You need to lock, send packet, unlock

Comment: Would it be possible / desirable to recode this as a state machine using select() or poll()? This might perform better than a threaded design, and avoids all those irritating thread sync issues!

Comment: @Raam This is a simulation work in my research, TCP traffic model is not considered. The reliability of transmission is ensured by the application layer.

Comment: Hi, @SimonElliott, using select() looks like a really good idea. I will look into it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Update: @SimonElliott Seems using select() is not working here. Because the worker socket is always available for sending(it's UDP), it still starves the listener socket. I'm afraid I would have to deal with multi-threading now... :-(

Comment: Using select() does not "starve" the listener socket. select() returns (when called appropriately, of course) whether there is a message packet readable from the listener socket; if this is the case, process it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is strong contention for your `peers_context` then you need to need to shorten your critical sections. You talked about using a mutex. I assume you've already considered changing to a reader+writer lock and rejected it because you don't want the constant readers to starve a writer. How about this?

Make a very small structure that is an indirect reference to a `peers_context` like this:

```
struct peers_context_handle {
    pthread_mutex_t ref_lock;
    struct peers_context *the_actual_context;
    pthread_mutex_t write_lock;
};
```

Packet senders (readers) and control request processors (writers) always access the `peers_mutex` through this indirection.

Assumption: the packet senders never modify the `peers_context`, nor do they ever free it.

Packer senders briefly lock the handle, obtain the current version of the `peers_context` and unlock it:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(handle->ref_lock));
peers_context = handle->the_actual_context;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(handle->ref_lock));
```

(In practice, you can even do away with the lock if you introduce memory barriers, because a pointer dereference is atomic on all platforms that Linux supports, but I wouldn't recommend it since you would have to start delving into memory barriers and other low-level stuff, and neither C nor POSIX guarantees that it will work anyway.)

Request processors don't update the `peers_context`, they make a copy and completely replace it. That's how they keep their critical section small. They *do* use `write_lock` to serialize updates, but updates are infrequent so that's not a problem.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(handle->write_lock));

/* Short CS to get the old version */
pthread_mutex_lock(&(handle->ref_lock));
old_peers_context = handle->the_actual_context;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(handle->ref_lock));

new_peers_context = allocate_new_structure();
*new_peers_context = *old_peers_context;

/* Now make the changes that are requested */
new_peers_context->foo = 42;
new_peers_context->bar = 52;

/* Short CS to replace the context */
pthread_mutex_lock(&(handle->ref_lock));
handle->the_actual_context = new_peers_context;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(handle->ref_lock));

pthread_mutex_unlock(&(handle->write_lock));

magic(old_peers_context);
```

What's the catch? It's the magic in the last line of code. You have to free the old copy of the `peers_context` to avoid a memory leak but you can't do it because there might be packet senders still using that copy.

The solution is similar to [RCU](http://lwn.net/Articles/262464/), as used inside the Linux kernel. You have to wait for all of the packet sender threads to have entered a quiescent state. I'm leaving the implementation of this as an exercise for you :-) but here are the guidelines:

- The `magic()` function adds `old_peers_context` so a to-be-freed queue (which has to be protected by a mutex).
- One dedicated thread frees this list in a loop:

  1. It locks the to-be-freed list
  2. It obtains a pointer to the list
  3. It replaced the list with a new empty list
  4. It unlocks the to-be-freed list
  5. It clears a mark associated with each worker thread
  6. It waits for all marks to be set again
  7. It frees each item in its previously obtained copy of the to-be-freed list
- Meanwhile, each worker thread sets its own mark at an idle point in its event loop (i.e. a point when it is not busy sending any packets or holding any `peer_contexts`.

Comment: Hi @Celada, thanks sincerely for your kind reply. This knowledge is quite helpful. One thing I'm a little confused is in the "magic" part, how would I know when the packet sender has entered a quiescent state and let the `free_old_peers_context` thread know it? As I mentioned, the packet sender would keep sending packets as long as there is at least one peer in active in the `peers_context`. (Normally I traverse the peers list once, and send packet to each of them, and traverse the list again and again, maybe I should add an idle point here?) Thanks again.

Comment: You have to arrange for your application to have a quiescent state. If you use an event loop (likely, since you are IO-bound) then it's right before or after you call `poll()`.

Comment: You mean inside or outside the sending loop? The thing is, either select() or poll() will block the sender, which means, I can only send once when the monitoring socket is readable. For your information, here is a segment of my codes [link](http://pastebin.com/XB73mLUF). (I haven't start applying your reader-writer spin lock yet.)

Comment: The code fragment you pasted seems to be related to waiting for messages on the control sockets. I thought you had worker threads that were sending packets continuously or frequently. These are the ones that need to have quiescent states. I suggest right before of after `poll()` in *those* threads.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @Celada Actually what I NEED is exactly to have a worker thread sending packets continuously. That was what the `while(peer!=NULL)` part in my code fragment supposed to do. But obviously that is not working with those codes... I need a worker thread sending packets continuously, while at the same time, if some control packets coming from `ctrl_sock`, it can update `c_ctx` accordingly and also let the worker thread see the update. By the way, there is only one `data_sock` in the worker thread, what `poll()` is needed? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know if `poll()` is needed or used or not in your worker thread. I figured you might have an event loop that picks up the packets from whatever generates them or an event loop that waits for the `data_sock` to be ready to send (`POLLOUT`) but if that's not how your worker thread is designed, that's fine too. But you're sending pakets one after another. You must have a loop of SOME KIND in there. And does that loop not have a quiescent point, a point at which it is guaranteed that no `peer_context` structures are being held?